# Retrieve password policy values Sap ase sybase

Tags: sybase

For a client, I try to get the password settings in order to check for complexity.
However I'm not able to get the sp_passwordpolicy values. Because when I run the command with the user sapsa on the user database, it says :

You must have the following permission to execute this command :'manage security configuration'.
Please contact a user with appropriate permission for help.

My question is which user do I need to retrieve the sp_passwordpolicy.
Do I need Sa, or the database owner role or which one?
And do I have to run the command for the user database or master?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything password or security related is generally the role of the SSO (System Security Officer) rather than SA (System Administrator). Granting sso_role to your login will also allow access to run the procedure as an alternative to 'manager security configuration'.

You can run the procedure from any database.